# Calculus, working backwards with differentiation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

trying to solve this question. Please help me

The graph of $y=f(x)$ passes through the point $(1,4)$ and $y'=2x+7$. Find $f(x)$.

I've so far gotten it to equate $y=x^2 +7x$ .....

Please help me complete it.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$y=x^2+7x+C$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant

Now this curve passes through $(1,4)$ so will satisfy the above equation

Answer (score 1):

You've integrated y'(x) properly. The only thing that you need to do is find out the constant C that makes the initial condition true.

$$y=x^2+7x+C$$

The initial condition is that the line passes through $(1,4)$:
$$ 4 = (1)^2+7(1)+C$$
$$ 4 = 1+7+C $$
$$ -4 = C $$

Therefore we have:

$$ y=x^2+7x-4$$

Hope that helps.